# poly() and orthogonal polynomials

Tags: r, regression, linear-algebra, linear-regression

I searched about `poly()` in R and I think it should produce orthogonal polynomials so when we use it in regression model like `lm(y~poly(x,2))` the predictors are uncorrelated. However:

```
poly(1:3,2)=
[1,] -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
[2,] -7.850462e-17 -0.8164966
[3,]  7.071068e-01  0.4082483
```

I think this is probably a stupid question but what I don't understand is the column vectors of the result `poly(1:3,2)` does not have inner product zero? That is  `-7.07*0.40-7.85*(-0.82)+7.07*0.41=/ 0`? so how is this uncorrelated predictors for regression?

Comment: `e-17` means `10^-17`

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that you're missing the meaning of the `e` or ["E notation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation): as commented by @MamounBenghezal above, `fff`**e**`ggg` is shorthand for `fff * 10^(ggg)`

I get *slightly* different answers than you do (the difference is numerically trivial) because I'm running this on a different platform:

```
pp <- poly(1:3,2)
##                  1          2
## [1,] -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
## [2,]  4.350720e-18 -0.8164966
## [3,]  7.071068e-01  0.4082483
```

An easier format to see:

```
print(zapsmall(matrix(c(pp),3,2)),digits=3)
##        [,1]   [,2]
## [1,] -0.707  0.408
## [2,]  0.000 -0.816
## [3,]  0.707  0.408

sum(pp[,1]*pp[,2]) ## 5.196039e-17, effectively zero
```

Or to use your example, with the correct placement of decimal points:

```
-0.707*0.408-(7.85e-17)*(-0.82)+(0.707)*0.408
## [1] 5.551115e-17
```